# How many ways can we put $m$ people in the circle with $m+r$ identical seats?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $m$ different people and a **circle** that has $m+r$ identical seats.  How many ways can we put those people in the circle?

If the seats were not identical then the solution was: $ \frac{1*(m+r-1)!}{r!} $

I can't understand how the fact that the seats are identical affects my solution? Is the only difference which guy is next to which one?

For example: $n=4 , r=2 $ , are those all options the same?

(the numbers representing a specific man and $X$ representing an empty seat) $(1,X,2,X,3,4,1) = (1,X,2,X,4,3,1) = (1,X,X,2,3,4,1)$ ?

What can I understand if the question will be changed to identical $m+r$ seats (not a circle) ?

Thank you,

Stav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First imagine that one seat is marked. Then we can think of the seats as actually being arranged in a line, with the marked seat at the beginning of the line. There are $\binom{m+r}m$ ways to pick $m$ of the seats to be occupied by people, and those $m$ people can be arranged in $m!$ ways in the chosen seats, so there are

$$\binom{m+r}mm!=\frac{(m+r)!}{r!}\tag{1}$$

ways to seat the people, *not* $\dfrac{(m+r-1)!}{r!}$.

Now in your example consider the arrangements

$$\begin{align*}&\langle 1,X,2,X,3,4\rangle,\langle X,2,X,3,4,1\rangle,\langle 2,X,3,4,1,X\rangle,\langle X,3,4,1,X,2\rangle,\langle 3,4,1,X,2,X\rangle,\\
&\text{and }\langle 4,1,X,2,X,3\rangle\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the first entry in each tuple corresponds to the marked seat. If we remove the marking, making the seats identical, these $6$ arrangements can no longer be distinguished: the only thing that distinguished them before was the marking on the one seat that let us decide which seat was the first to be listed.

More generally, the $m+r$ circular permutations of a given seating are all indistinguishable when the seats are identical: there is simply no way to pick out one of the $m+r$ entries in the tuple to be the first one. Thus, each *distinguishable* arrangement when the seats are identical is counted $m+r$ times by $(1)$, and there are therefore only

$$\frac1{m+r}\cdot\frac{(m+r)!}{r!}=\frac{(m+r-1)!}{r!}$$

distinguishable arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the identical seats consider this

Example: for combination it would be that first select any one of the persons among $m$ then chose a seat for him and because all seats are identical hence there is no restriction so you have to choose from $n$ seats i.e. $^mC_1.^{n}C_1$, then pickup a seat again from $n-1$ and pick a person from $m-1$, again there is no restriction on choosing seats(as all seats are identical) hence this time it is $^{m-1}C_1.^{n-1}C_1$...and it goes on like this..

permutations will be $(m+r-1)!$ if they are being seated in a circle because in a circle there is no starting point so you have to wait till you get a staring point i.e. when the first person sits on any of the one seats. but if it not a circle then you know your starting point i.e. you don't have to wait for any other event to happen, permutations will be in this case $(m+r)!$

and you know combinations are calculated using permutations.

Comment: Can you explain what does C and CC means?

Comment: @Stav: Not sure what you mean by CC, but $^aC_b$ is standard notation for "the number of ways to choose $b$ objects from a collection of $a$ objects", which is also often written $\binom{a}{b}$.

Comment: Okay thanks alot. and what does $CC_a^{b}$ stands for?